# Can a PSVita download DLC for a PSP?

Tags: ps-vita, psp

My main PSP which is the original model however it wont connect to my wireless network cause it seems to be incompatible with the WPA Security on it, I'm planning on getting a PS Vita and from what i heard PSP games are backwards compatible on it so can I download PSP DLC using it (cause obviously the Vita would be compatible with WPA Security)

I ask this as I just got Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days and learned there is DLC for it, since I'm playing Disgaea: Afternoon of Darkness at the moment I do have time before I want to download all the DLC for Disgaea 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vita has a built-in psp emulator. The psp games you can play you have to buy from psn first. Some games offer dlc, but for some it doesn't work, or is not available on psn. It's all a bit sketchy. I you just want the dlc, I suggest investigating network issues to make your psp work first, if you are using WPA security, try switching to WPA2 because WPA is obsolete. If this doesn't work out for you, do some googling to see if others were able to get the dlc working on their vita.

In short: It is most certainly possible to get the game and the dlc on your vita, but it all depends on Sony if it will work or is even available.